# Git config file error

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I am getting this warming when i run any git command from terminal . I thouht it was a permission issue  but can't seem to fix. Can anybody point me to the right direction ? below is the warming and 
the content of my .config file

```
Innos-MacBook-Pro:turnit_try innomanyo$ git status
warning: unable to access '/Users/innomanyo/.config/git/config': Not a directory
warning: unable to access '/Users/innomanyo/.config/git/config': Not a directory
warning: unable to access '/Users/innomanyo/.config/git/config': Not a directory




Innos-MacBook-Pro:~ innomanyo$ cat .config
# bash completion related
source ~/git-completion.bash
alias gco='git co'
alias gci='git ci'
alias grb='git rb'

-rw-r--r--    1 innomanyo  staff    112 Jul 19 12:09 .config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.config` file should be a directory. This is a newish standard location on posix systems for applications data. So you will need to remove this file and replace it with a `.config` directory. Looks like what you have should be in `.bashrc`. If you do this:

```
cd 
cat .config >> .bashrc
rm .config
mkdir -p .config/git/config
```

Then you will be back on track and your other applications will be happy as well.